# component lifecycle in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have built a component as follows

```
export class AcknowledgementComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private description: string;

  @Input('period') period: string;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.period)
  }
```

I have to perform some logic with that variable before using it in the template. But in `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`, the variable is undefined. Can someone advise which hook to use in order to get the variable?

Comment: where are you setting this component? can you add that html?

Comment: <acknowledgement-msg [period]="period" </acknowledgement-msg> this is how I am using the component in another template.

Comment: and `period` is a variable in the parent component right?

Comment: @suraj yes basically passing the variable period into the child component. maybe i should have renamed the variables for clarity.

Comment: maybe its a naming clash? try renaming the variable...

Comment: nope still undefined. But what is weird is that I can display the variable in the child component template using {{}} but it is undefined in the hooks.

Comment: Do you have any plnkr for this ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi nope. I'll try to build one.

Comment: Great That will be very useful and can debug it very quicky then

Comment: Try to give your varible an initial value: `@Input('period') period: string =""`; and use it in `ionViewDidEnter`

Comment: @Duannx It is a custom component not an ionic page.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the input property in two ways:

**[Using a setter:](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter)**

```
export class AcknowledgementComponent {
    private _period = "";

    @Input('period')
    set period(period:string) {
        this._period = (period && period.toUpperCase()) || 'No input';
    }
    // Works with async operations. Emample:
    // set period(period:string) {
    //     setTimeout(() => {
    //         this._period = (period && period.toUpperCase()) || 'No input';
    //     }, 5000);
    // }

    get period():string { return this._period; }
}
```

**[Using `ngOnChanges`:](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges)**

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
...
export class AcknowledgementComponent {
    @Input() period;

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[ propKey: string ]: SimpleChanges}){
        this.period = '';

        for(let propName in changes) {
            let changedProp = changes[propName];
            let newValue:string = String(changedProp.currentValue);
            this.period = newValue.toUpperCase();

            // Works with async operations. Emample:
            // setTimeout(() => {
            //     this.period = (newValue && newValue.toUpperCase()) || 'No input';
            // }, 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

These examples simply makes the input `string` upper case.